# Achieve async operation without using deferred

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am stuck with the **async** operation where I have a method that doing some **UI animation** work, and I need to execute another block of code **after the Completion** of my UI animation.  for example:

```
function myAsyncOperation() {
// my UI animation gets completed over here
}
myAsyncOperation();
//after calling that function I need to print console.
console.log("Hello world");
```

**NOTE**: I know that I can use the **deferred** in **myAsyncOperation** function and return the deferred from the function and then execute the console after it. but I want to achieve it without deferred as I have some **limitation**.

Comment: Can you use callbacks? It will change code structure but it can be a feasible option

Comment: What's your limitation? This appears to be an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve? What do you _need_ this for?

Comment: How do you know when your `UI animation` is finished?

Comment: Yes, I can use callbacks. My limitation is that if I use deferred in myAsyncOperation then I need to return def from my function and have to put my another block of code in .then() function but I cannot do so. what I can do is I have to write myAsyncOperation in such a way that only when this function is executed after that my another block of code should get executed.

Comment: The reason is that if I use the deferred then it leads me to performance issues and also increases the complexity of the code since I am working on open source project I have to make the code as simple as i can and also have to take care of code complexity since it will get used by other developers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using CSS animations, you can use the "animationend" event in javascript.

```
var anim = document.getElementById("anim");
anim.addEventListener("animationend", AnimationListener, false);
```

various browsers have different implementations of this event listener, so look up the right event name for the browsers you need to support and implement all of them

https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/